# Tefillin on erev pesach after chatzos

Tags: passover, tefilin

If one brought Korban pesach and didn’t put on tefillin would he put it on after since it’s still midday or do we say since it’s chag hapesach biblically then it’s like chol hamoed? And would the same apply today even though there is no Korban pesach? (What we refer to as pesach nowadays is really chag hamatzot.)

Comment: I was just thinking about this! Seemingly this is a strong question on the opinions that you do not wear tefillin on chol hamoed, since the "sign" of chametz/work started already the day before at noon.

Comment: Realize that tefillin are obligatory all day and were worn as such the last time a Pesach was brought. The question should be framed as "did everyone wear their tefillin while offering the Pesach?"

Comment: We remove them even for mussaf on Rosh Chodesh! And Rosh Chodesh isn’t a chag. So logically you would remove them for Korban pesach

Comment: many people nowadays do but no one back then did. That is a much later minhag

Comment: Even second day yom tov is difficult why we dont wear t'fillin. The reason given is not to be mezalzel in it. Chol hamoed is I think a kabala thing and unless you know kabala cant give answers on erev pesach.

Comment: *since it’s chag hapesach biblically then it’s like chol hamoed...* What's the basis for this?

Comment: http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=17808

Comment: @DoubleAA Interesting. He raises the question and brings a proof that it's permitted, but doesn't explain why.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that  the איסור of חמץ on ערב פסח cannot be completely considered an ״אות״, because the reason for it is seemingly not necessarily  to be a reminder of ״יציאת מצרים״ but rather as a result of the fact that the קרבן פסח is brought then, which is only a preparation for the night of פסח, being that you can’t bring a sacrifice by night

Also it’s obviously not exactly  like חול המועד - there is no חיוב שמחה, and you can’t bring the קרבן ראי׳ and חגיגת הרגל then either, and even the איסור מלאכה is more lenient and only מדרבנן because of the קרבן פסח, no הלל or יעלה ויבא or anything special in שמונה עשרה.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for your first answers. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. See in particular the focus on writing in English to enable as many participants to understand content on the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Is the issur melacha tied to לא תשחט על חמץ?

Comment: No, but it is still because of the קרבן פסח - from ירושלמי פסחים פרק ד׳, also mentioned in תוספות; and according to רש״י, also a גזירה in order to be available to prepare for the סדר.

Comment: The idea of kedushat hayom is interesting, but we find Hallel and YY on chanuka and Rosh Chodesh respectively, and we don't find them on chol hamoed pesach and shabbat respectively, so I'm not sure how those are proofs

Comment: A problem with this (besides proving conclusively that erev pesach afternoon doesn't have kedushat zman) is many rishonim say the reason we don't wear tefillin is the אות of the mitzva of matza/chametz not some kedushat hayom of chol hamoed.

Comment: Now name is the relevant factor? The 14th of Nissan has a very specific traditional name: בַּחֹדֶשׁ הָרִאשׁוֹן, בְּאַרְבָּעָה עָשָׂר לַחֹדֶשׁ--בֵּין הָעַרְבָּיִם:  פֶּסַח, לַיהוָה.

Comment: A more lenient issur melacha isn't a proof on its own. After all, the whole thing is based on chol hamoed which is unquestionably a weaker issur melacha than Yom Tov.

Comment: There davka was חגיגת י"ד. That's why we have an egg on the seder plate

Comment: Right, but you can’t be יוצא ידי חגיגת הרגל with it

Comment: You keep pointing out differences but I keep pointing out that it's not obvious if they are sufficiently different.

Comment: Let’s say someone was עובר on the אות - he still wouldn’t have to put on תפילין - so wouldn’t that prove that it has nothing to do with the גברא performing the אות but rather the חפצא of the   זמן?

Comment: …חפצא of the זמן which causes the חיוב of the אות

Comment: However, regarding ערב פסח - on the contrary - מהיכא תיתי that it has any קדושת זמן - the fact that we bring the קרבן פסח then doesn’t prove anything, because the קרבן isn’t brought in honor of ערב פסח, but rather for ליל פסח itself, but since you can’t bring a קרבן by night, there is no choice but to bring it on ערב פסח, so being that the איסור of חמץ comes as a result of the קרבן פסח,  it would come out that it has nothing to do with the חפצא of the זמן

Comment: So how can it be an אות if it’s only coming as a preparation for a later time - not as a זכר  ליציאת מצרים?

Comment: You keep pointing out differences but I keep pointing out that it's not obvious if they are sufficiently different. There clearly is something unique about the 14th afternoon. You are presenting one very minimalist conception of that, but it's not obvious that should be so or that that should be sufficient to allow tefillin (for those who prohibit on chol hamoed). We can point out other things, like hallel in the mikdash and when baking matza, shechita being the issur karet not achila, avelut being cancelled, not to mention the mashmaus of the psukim, that indicate significance to the 14th.

Comment: It's important to remember no one is really questioning that tfillin applies on erev pesach. What we are trying to figure out is what exactly is the 'level' of אות that would make tefillin not appropriate and then we can prove an upper bound for how unique the 14th of nissan is for the rishonim who don't allow tefillin on chol hamoed.